# Foundation Magellan - check if it's sticky

Tags: zurb-foundation, sticky, magellan

How can I check with JS if the Magellan bar (or the element I added `"data-magellan-expedition='fixed'"`) is sticky while scrolling?

I want to add a class if it's sticky. Otherwise the class should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the below script end of page (with the other scripts) then using the .navstuck class in my SCSS worked for me:

```js
<!--for Sticky Nav per http://codepen.io/zurbchris/pen/rxMaoX-->
      <script>
          $(document).foundation();
          $('.sticky').on('sticky.zf.stuckto:top', function(){
              $(this).addClass('navstuck');
          }).on('sticky.zf.unstuckfrom:top', function(){
              $(this).removeClass('navstuck');
          })
          console.log(Foundation.version);
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

when the sticky is activated the `div` gets a css attr of

```
style="position: fixed; top: 0px;"
```

thus you can use that to add a class

```
if ($('#yourElement').css('position') == 'fixed')
{
  // true
}
```